# Help understanding passage from combinatorics book.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently reading Niven's "Mathematics of Choice." This passage has me a bit tied up in knots, as I can't really understand what he's saying.

"If $m$ objects, no two alike, are to be distributed in $k$ boxes, no two alike, the number of ways this can be done is $k^m$ since there are $k$ alternatives for the disposal of the first object, $k$ alternatives for the disposal of the second, and so on."

This is freaking me out. I feel like this should be $P(m,k)$, not $k^m$. After placing the first of $m$ objects into $k$ boxes, it seems like there should then only be $k-1$ options for the disposal of the second object, not $k$ options.

He then goes on to define the function $f(m,k)$, which gives the number of ways to put $m$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct boxes given that $m\ge k$. He then derives a formula via the inclusion-exclusion principle. I don't really understand why he would do this, since as far as I can tell $f(m,k)$ is the same as $P(m,k)$, the permutation function. My feelings seem to be confirmed by the examples.

What am I missing?

Comment: Each box is large enough to contain as many of your objects as you care to put into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming he is saying that the objects do not necessarily have to be placed in different boxes. So the first object to be placed as $k$ choices. The second object can be placed in the same box or one of the other $k-1$ boxes, leaving $k$ total choices, meaning there are 
$$
\underbrace{k\cdot k \cdots k}_{\text{m times}}=k^m
$$
possible ways of doing this.

Comment: Wow that was really dumb of me. Thanks. It's always something like that. That wasn't specified, but now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: It happens to the best of us from time to time.